# Why do @Html.Action @Html.RenderAction not work in MVC .Net 8 project ? How can I pass data to a partial view from chosen by me controller and action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-8.0

I am trying to render partial view with data from Card controller in the `\_Layout.cshtml`. The problem is only `@Html.Partial` works. I said to myself: "Okay, i will try to pass the necessary data with ViewBag or ViewDate or even with dynamic model", but this did not work too. It only renders the view but with no data in it. It even does not go to the controller func while debugging.

Sidebar.cshtml:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">&times;</a>
@if (ViewBag.Cards != null)
{
    @foreach (var card in ViewBag.Cards)
    {
        <a>@card.Number</a>
    }
}
else
{
    <p>No cards available.</p>
}
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@Html.Partial("SideBar")
```

CardContoller:

```
var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var cards = await cardService.GetAllCardsAsync(user.Id);

cards = cards.Select(c => new CardViewModel
{
    Id = c.Id,
    Balance = c.Balance,
    Number = c.Number,
    Transactions = c.Transactions
});

ViewBag.Cards = cards;
return PartialView("Sidebar",cards);`
```

Comment: You should _materialize_ your `cards` collection - otherwise it'll hit your DB multiple times during a single page-load and lose mutated state.

Comment: Also, you aren't using `@Html.Action` anywhere in your posted code... as for `@Html.Partial` - [you need to use `@await Html.PartialAsync( "View.cshtml" )` now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"@Html.Action" is for old .net framework. In .net8 (asp.net core) You could try using ViewComponent. Try following:

1. create a class `MyPagesViewComponent.cs`

```
    public class MyPagesViewComponent: ViewComponent
    {
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            string model = "test passing value";  //of course you can pass your object 

            return View("childPage1",model);
        }
    }
```

2. Create folders and "childPage1.cshtml" like following hierarchy
   [image]
   childPage1.cshtml

```
@model string    //pass model type

@Model      // display model value
```

3. In _Layout.cshtml add following code to somewhere

```
...
  @await Component.InvokeAsync("MyPages")
...
```

Result
[image]

Comment: ViewComponents means Blazor - which is a whole other platform. That's unnecessary for just rendering some Razor `.cshtml` partial-views.